# Is it possible to conditionally shift data in a vector n columns to the right

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm new to R and the tidyverse and have some data that I'm trying to tidy-up.  There seems to have been a parsing problem so some of the data is not in the correct column.  For example in the table below you can see that Jim Smith, Jr and Jim Smith Senior's column are shifted because the first column did not parse correctly:

[image]

Im looking to find a way to correct this so all of the column line up correctly:

[image]

Then I can use some stringr functionality to clean up the Name column:

[image]

My thought was to use ifelse to determine if the Paid column is blank, if true use some kind of shift functionality to move all the columns one to the right, if false - do nothing.  Does the tidyverse have a function that can sift multiple columns at a time or is this something that will require a custome function.

Comment: Can you provide some data in a code format? How do you load the data in? Maybe it is easier to fix it that way.

Comment: Please give reproducible examples

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I wasn't aware of dput. I just checked out a youtube video on it and will use it in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform the data to a long format and use `lag` to shift the values, depending on the condition you specified. A working example:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = letters[1:5],
                 Gender = c("M","F","26","27","M"),
                 Age = 1:5,
                 Years = c("10","20","yes","no","30"),
                 Paid = c("yes","yes",NA,NA,"no"))
```

data:

```
  Name Gender Age Years Paid
1    a      M   1    10  yes
2    b      F   2    20  yes
3    c     26   3   yes <NA>
4    d     27   4    no <NA>
5    e      M   5    30   no
```

shift:

```
df %>%
  mutate(shifted = if_else(is.na(Paid),1,0)) %>%
  gather(key, value,-Name,-shifted) %>%
  mutate(key = factor(key,levels = names(df))) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(key) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(shifted == 1, lag(value),value)) %>%
  select(-shifted) %>%
  spread(key,value)
```

result:

```
  Name  Gender Age   Years Paid 
  <fct> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     M      1     10    yes  
2 b     F      2     20    yes  
3 c     NA     26    3     yes  
4 d     NA     27    4     no   
5 e     M      5     30    no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with base R.

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(Name = letters[1:5],
             Gender = c("M","F","26","27","M"),
             Age = 1:5,
             Years = c("10","20","yes","no","30"),
             Paid = c("yes","yes",NA,NA,"no"), 
             stringsAsFactors = F)
```

#### Shifting

```
# Identifying which rows to shift
rows_to_change <- !df$Gender %in% c("M", "F")

# Moving columns one space to the right
df[rows_to_change,3:5] <- df[rows_to_change,2:4] 

# Deleting wrong values
df[rows_to_change,2] <- NA
```

#### Output

```
Name Gender Age Years Paid
a      M   1    10  yes
b      F   2    20  yes
c   <NA>  26     3  yes
d   <NA>  27     4   no
e      M   5    30   no
```